# window width only showing when resizing viewport, not on load - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to get viewport width on page load and when resizing browser window. For some reason the width isn't being outputted on page load. Any idea what the issue is and/or how to resolve?

```
function mobileViewUpdate() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    console.log(viewportWidth);
    if (viewportWidth > 776) {
        $("area[data-toggle]").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
            var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
            $(".detail-box").hide();
            $(".detail-box"+selector).show().addClass('animated fadeIn');
        });
    }
}

$(window).on('load, resize', mobileViewUpdate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of `,` as separator. Separation by space will work . Please refer this [**link**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/) for more informaton

```
$(window).on('load resize', mobileViewUpdate);
```

Comment: that throws console log error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @frshjb373 it is working fine check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsm6pwyL/)

Comment: yup...made a fix and it's working per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are calling this function **within** a **ready function**, in that case window has already loaded and so the window load event has already been called.

Attaching the load event handler at that point will never be called.